# PHP prevent duplicate post

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have the code below that updates user information. I need to run the query ONLY for the fields that are filled in, so you dont have to add all the info every time you want to make a little edit to a user. I want to IGNORE the empty form fields

I cant figure out what method to go with to achieve this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['do_edit'])) {


    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
    $company_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company_name']);
    $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirm']);
    $level = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_level']);
    $restrict = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['restrict']);

    $delete = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete']);

    // Ticked the 'delete user' box? If so, delete and echo message.    
    if($delete == 'delete_uid' && $error == '') {

    $sql = "DELETE FROM login_users WHERE user_id='$id'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Fatal error: ".mysql_error());

    echo "<h3>Deleted</h3>";
    echo "<div class='success_message'>User <b>$company_name $contact</b> has been removed from the database.</div>";

    echo "<h2>What to do now?</h2><br />";
    echo "<a href=''>&laquo; Back to Admin Panel</a> | Go to the <a href='user_edit.php'>edit users</a> page.</li>";

    } else {

    // Validate the submitted information

        if(trim($id) == '1') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! You cannot edit the main Administrator, use database.</div>';
        } else if(trim($company_name) == '') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter a company name.</div>';
        } else if(trim($contact) == '') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter a contact name.</div>';
        } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have entered an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
        } else if(trim($level) == '') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! No user level has been selected.</div>';
        }

    // Password been entered? If so, validate and update information.

        if($password != '') {

            if($password != $password2) {
                $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! Your passwords did not match.</div>';
            }

            if(strlen($password) < 5) {
                $error = '<div class="error_message">Attention! Your password must be at least 5 characters.</div>';
            }

            if($error == '') {

            $sql = "UPDATE login_users SET restricted='$restrict', company_name='$company_name', contact='$contact', email='$email', user_level='$level', password = MD5('$password') WHERE user_id = '$id'";
            $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Fatal error: ".mysql_error());

            echo "<h2>Updated</h2>";
            echo "<div class='success_message'>User information (and password) updated for User ID <b>$id ($company_name)</b>.</div>";

            echo "<h2>What to do now?</h2><br />";
            echo "<a href=''>&laquo; Back to Admin Panel</a> | Go to the <a href='user_edit.php'>edit users</a> page.</li>";

            }

    // Password has not been entered don't update password fields.

        } else {

            if($error == '') {

            $sql = "UPDATE login_users SET restricted='$restrict', company_name='$company_name', contact='$contact', username='$username', email='$email', user_level='$level' WHERE user_id = '$id'";
            $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Fatal error: ".mysql_error());

            echo "<h2>Updated</h2>";
            echo "<div class='success_message'>User information updated for <b>$company_name</b>.</div>";

            echo "<h2>What to do now?</h2><br />";
            echo "<a href=''>&laquo; Back to Admin Panel</a> | Go to the <a href='user_edit.php'>edit users</a> page.</li>";

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can loop on $_POST variable and see what is set , according to this to build your query set.

Comment: if you don't want to prevent php from updating database, put `return` after `$error = ` in validation

Answer (score 1):

Check the list of fields, and dynamically build your UPDATE query based on the ones that meet the criteria. Strongly consider writing a function or two to help build the query without the repeated logic, but the following should provide a hint:

```
$sql = "UPDATE login_users SET ";
$first = 1;
if ($restrict != '') {
    if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
    } else {
        $query += ", ";
    }
    $query += "restricted='$restrict'";
}

if ($company_name != '') {
    if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
    } else {
        $query += ", ";
    }
    $query += "company_name='$company_name'";
}

if ($contact != '') {
    if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
    } else {
        $query += ", ";
    }
    $query += "contact='$contact'";
}

if ($username != '') {
    if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
    } else {
        $query += ", ";
    }
    $query += "username='$username'";
}

if ($email != '') {
    if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
    } else {
        $query += ", ";
    }
    $query += "email='$email'";
}

if ($level!= '') {
    if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
    } else {
        $query += ", ";
    }
    $query += "user_level='$level'";
}

$query += " WHERE user_id = '$id'";

if (! $first) {
    // do query, since we know something was changed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

- The one I usually use is to just use the database fields (except the password...) to pre-populate the form fields. They don't have to be empty.
- Start with an empty UPDATE query (`UPDATE login_users SET ? WHERE user_id=$id`) and construct a field='value',... string to replace the ?.

The second one seems more cumbersome than just prefilling the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE login_users SET ";
foreach ($_POST as $fieldname=>$value) {
    if ($value) {
        $sql .= "$fieldname='$value', ";
    }
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -2); // to remove the last ", "
$sql .= " WHERE user_id = '$id';";
```

Beware of two things:

1. $fieldname must be the same as the actual field name in your database (if not, you should do something to rename it).
2. You should do the md5 for passwords somewhere in between.

EDIT: Two more things!

1. Don't forget to do MySQL escaping.
2. This could be done prettier using [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)